# PHP - Not entering on the loop if route returns a string

Tags: php, pdo, slim, notorm

Im setting a small webservice that should return `true` if it finds the user, on the DB, and `false` if it doesn't. But its allways returning `false`.
In fact if I `echo` something on the `foreach` it doesn't return anything, and if I echo `$data` I get `Undefined variable: data`

I've tried to search with the id, and it seems fine

If I test with, for example, a route of `/api/users/login/{id}`, and alter the `foreach` to `foreach($db->user()->select('username', 'pass')->where('id', $id) as $row)`  it will execute correctly.

```
$app->get('/api/users/login/{username}/{password}', function($request){
    $username = $request -> getAttribute('username');
    $password = $request -> getAttribute('pass');
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    require_once('db/dbconnect.php');

    foreach($db->user()->select('username', 'pass')->where('username', 'pass', $username, $password) as $row){
        $data[] = $row;
    }



    if(isset($data)){
        echo json_encode(true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }else{
        echo json_encode(false, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }


});
```

Will the problem be that I'm going to fetch strings from the route? 
If so, how can I correct it?

Comment: This is not PDO, PDO might be the underlying driver but you should tag the framework you are using. This looks like plaintext passwords are being used, if that is the case please stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `where()` is not right, you should use it with an array of conditions.

From the [api](https://www.notorm.com/#api):

> `$table->where(array("field" => "x", "field2" => "y"))`
>
> Translated to `field = 'x' AND field2 = 'y'` (with automatic escaping)

```php
$db->user()->select('username', 'pass')->where([
    'username' => $username,
    'pass' => $password
])
```

Comment: hi, @iArcadia i´ve tried to do like you said but the result is the same it is returned `false`

Comment: @PauloAlexandreRioPreto - Are you sure that you have a database item which is corresponding to your inputs?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I was now checking and I was using "password" on the route and it was "pass"